# Dojo delegate to DOM Element's ID

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am working with a JSP that dynamically includes DOM elements such as a buttons based on a user's privilege or other factors.

Now, in my JS, I was using:
    `dojo.connect(dojo.byId('dispatchBtn'), 'onclick', function() { //logic }`

The problem is, if the 'dispatchBtn' doesn't exist because it was stripped based on the user's privilege, the JS just calls all the contents of the `"//logic"` anyway.

I tried to change this call to:
    `eventView.delegate(dojo.byId('dispatchBtn'), 'onclick', function() { //logic }`

But that doesn't seem to work at all, even for buttons that DO exist. What's the best way to do this without explicitly testing if the button exists. I do not want to change the markup on any of these button elements, no additional classes, just want to reference them by ID.

Comment: As an aside, why does the dojo.connect act like the statement isn't even there and continue on with all the logic? Shouldn't it just error out and not run?

Comment: If I understand what you are doing, your JSP (server side code) is deciding to add or not add button elements based on logic.  Your client side logic is then connecting those buttons to work to be done when clicked.  However, if the button is now injected ... what then.  This "feels" like a bad design.  I would say that it is invalid to attempt to "dojo.connect" to a null parameter.  Why not have the JSP inject the buttons (so that they are always there) but make them hidden if not needed.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean when you say that //logic is called. How is an event being triggered for an element that doesn't exist?

Comment: @Kolban I didn't want to hide the buttons in case people who don't have the right privileges decide to turn off JS or do something that makes these buttons appear again. Then again, if they turn off JS, the code that executes anything when the button is pressed won't run, so I guess that's not a bad idea.

Comment: @MattR that's exactly my question, basically it executes anything within that anonymous function even though the button doesn't exist. It acts as if the dojo.connect call doesn't exist and just continues on with all the logic inside that call... it makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like jquery live does and bind on the document level.

```
require(["dojo/on", "dojo/query"], function(on){
  on(document, "#dispatchBtn:click", function(evt){
        alert("Clicked on node " + this.id);
  });
});
```

Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/theinnkeeper/NTn6g/

Answer (score 0):

Why are you adverse to checking if the button exists? That makes the most sense

```
var btn = dojo.byId("dispatchBtn");
 if(btn) {
    on(btn, 'onclick', function() {});
}
```

Comment: Well, I wouldn't say I'm adverse to it, I just want to avoid extra lines of code if there's a Dojo function that doesn't cause the `//logic` to be executed if the element doesn't exist. (like the problem i'm seeing with the connect function)